# Как изменить значение полей при сбросе пароля в Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel5

Есть проект на Laravel 5.4 в котором используется вордпресс, база данных у них общая в которой таблицы лары и вп. Laravel использует `wp_user` для регистрации и логина.

В файле `my-reset.blade.php` eсть форма (взял из файла reset.blade.php) для сброса пароля. В этой форме value полей такие: `email`, `password`, `password-confirmation`.

Мне нужно такие: `user_email`, `user_pass`; поле `password-confirmation` остается таким.

Laravel из коробки получаем емейл из столбца `email` но так как я изменил таблицу то мне теперь нужно получать емейл из `user_email` и пароль который я сбрасываю записывать в `user_pass`, а не в `password`.

Как можно перебить `password` на `user_pass`? В движок `ResetPassword.php` лезть нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Переопределите методы в контроллере **ResetPasswordController**

```
/**
 * Get the password reset validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'user_email' => 'required|email',
        'user_pass' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
}
```

и еще один метод

```
/**
 * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only(
        'user_email', 'user_pass', 'user_pass_confirmation', 'token'
    );
}
```

и обратите внимание что поле для конфирмации пароля нужно будет указать как **user_pass_confirmation**

Так как в **Laravel** при правиле **validate** оно так определяется. Более подробнее об этом [здесь](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-confirmed)

И не забудьте указать в данном контроллере

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```